# Auto update specifick plugin

Tags: plugin-development, automatic-updates

I've created a plugin and I want to auto-update this plugin.

I've been looking in the WordPress Codex and found this following piece of code:

```
add_filter( 'auto_update_plugin', '__return_true' );
```

I added this code into a new Must-have Plugin but it doesn't work. It does not auto-update all my plug-ins..

Anyone that have experience with auto updating?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update/auto-update my private plugin?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/259346/how-to-update-auto-update-my-private-plugin)

Comment: Not really, flagged it already. Hope it gets deleted soon!